# ¿Cómo puedo obtener los datos correctamente para editar en jsp javascript, rest, url servlet?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, rest, servlets

No logro obtener específicamente el dato "distrito" para que se muestre automáticamente en el combo correspondiente de la interfaz "Editar".

Tengo una lista con todos los docentes, cuando hago click en el botón "Editar" automáticamente carga todos los datos del docente que seleccioné pero, por alguna razón, el distrito no carga, no logra obtener el dato.

Con SOAP todo sale bien pero con REST por alguna razón no carga el distrito en el combo.

---

Esta es la interfaz "Editar", como pueden ver, todo carga, menos el combo del distrito.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Este es el codigo de Registro en el servlet donde realizo el PUT. utilizo "url" donde "DOCENTEREST" es el objeto para la url de docente.

```
private void RegistrarDocente(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{
    String dataJson=request.getParameter("jsonTex");
    Gson json=new Gson();
    ClientResponse clientResponse=null;
    DocenteInst bean=json.fromJson(dataJson, DocenteInst.class);
    if(bean.getCodDoc()==0) {
        WebResource webResource=client.resource(DOCENTEREST);
        clientResponse=webResource.type("application/json").post(ClientResponse.class,dataJson);
    }else {
        WebResource webResource=client.resource(DOCENTEREST);
        clientResponse=webResource.type("application/json").put(ClientResponse.class,dataJson);
    }
    String json2=clientResponse.getEntity(String.class);
    response.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter salida=response.getWriter();
    salida.println(json2);
}
```

---

Este es la función en Javascript donde está el botón "editar".

```
function tablaDocente(){
    $("#id_table_docente").DataTable().destroy();
    $("#id_table_docente tbody").empty(); 
    $.getJSON("ServletFrancoInstituto",{metodo:"listadoDocentes"}, function (data){
        $.each(data, function(index, item){
            var editar='<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="editarDocente('+
                                                                                               item.codDoc+","+
                                                                                           "'"+item.nomDoc+"',"+
                                                                                           "'"+item.patDoc+"',"+
                                                                                           "'"+item.matDoc+"',"+
                                                                                           "'"+item.sexDoc+"',"+
                                                                                               item.hijDoc+","+
                                                                                               item.sueDoc+","+
                                                                                           "'"+item.dirDoc+"',"+
                                                                                               item.distrito.codDis+')">Editar</button>';
                                                                                           
           var eliminar='<button type="button" class="btn btn-btn-danger" onclick="eliminarDocente('+item.codDoc+')">Eliminar</button>';                                                                                        
            $("#id_table_docente").append("<tr><td>"+item.codDoc+"</td>"+
                                              "<td>"+item.nomDoc+"</td>"+
                                              "<td>"+item.patDoc+"</td>"+
                                              "<td>"+item.matDoc+"</td>"+
                                              "<td>"+item.sexDoc+"</td>"+
                                              "<td>"+item.hijDoc+"</td>"+
                                              "<td>"+item.sueDoc+"</td>"+
                                              "<td>"+item.dirDoc+"</td>"+
                                              "<td>"+item.distrito.nomDis+"</td>"+
                                              "<td>"+editar+"</td>"+
                                              "<td>"+eliminar+"</td>");
        });
        $("#id_table_docente").DataTable().draw();
        $("#id_table_docente").DataTable();
    });
}
```

---

Ésta es la función "editar".

```
function editarDocente(cod,nom,pat,mat,sexo,hijos,sueldo,direccion,distrito){
    $("#idCodigo").val(cod);        
    $("#idNombre").val(nom);
    $("#idPaterno").val(pat);
    $("#idMaterno").val(mat);
    $("#idSexo").val(sexo);
    $("#idHijos").val(hijos);
    $("#idSueldo").val(sueldo);
    $("#idDireccion").val(direccion);
    $("#idDistrito").val(distrito);
    $("#idMensaje").text("Actualizar Docente");
    $('#idModalRegistra').modal({backdrop: 'static',keyboard:false,show:true});
}
```

---

Un dato curioso en la realización de la entidades en el servicio:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver en la primera opción realizo la llamada de distrito mediante "int codigoDistrito", con esto sí logro obtener el distrito seleccionado en la interfaz "editar". Con la segunda opción, donde realizo la llamada con la entidad "DistritoInst", es en la que se genera el problema.

Ustilizo procedimientos almacenados.

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar el código de la entidad DistritoInst? Si te funciona cuando pasas un int, parece que el problema viene de que no estás accediendo correctamente a ese objeto.

Comment: Añadí la imagen de la entidad @PabloLozano